# removing a char at the end line of a page in python

Tags: python

The following code seems to work fine but it adds a period(.) at the end of the page. How can I remove the dot and where is that coming from? thank you for the help!
**Code**

```
with open("strings.txt") as inf:
    for line in inf:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.isalnum():
            print("{} was ok".format(line))
        else:
            print("{} was invalid".format(line))
```

**The following output should have been generated:**

```
5345m34534l was invalid.
no2no123non4 was ok.
noq234n5ioqw#% was invalid.
%#""SGMSGSER was invalid.
doghdp5234 was ok.
sg,dermoepm was invalid.
43453-frgsd was invalid.
hsth())) was invalid.
bmepm35wae was ok.
vmopaem2234+0+ was invalid.
gsdm12313 was ok.
gswrgsrdgrsgsig45 was ok.
)/(/)(#=%#)%/ was invalid.
++-+-+--+--+-+>-<+-<<_<-+>>++ was invalid.
```

**Your program generated the following output:**

```
5345m34534l was invalid.
no2no123non4 was ok.
noq234n5ioqw#% was invalid.
%#""SGMSGSER was invalid.
doghdp5234 was ok.
sg,dermoepm was invalid.
43453-frgsd was invalid.
hsth())) was invalid.
bmepm35wae was ok.
vmopaem2234+0+ was invalid.
gsdm12313 was ok.
gswrgsrdgrsgsig45 was ok.
)/(/)(#=%#)%/ was invalid.
++-+-+--+--+-+>-<+-<<_<-+>>++. was invalid.
```

Comment: So, the input file does not have the period at the end?

Comment: Hi, the input file is not mine, the program inputs an input file to test the code if it works fine. I guess the code is adding a period at the end of the page before "was invalid". Look at the last lines of both outputs that my output has a period before "was invalid"

Comment: There is nothing in the code that could 'add' a period at the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your exact question related to period(.) at the end of the page. But what I can tell you is if you want to remove any character which you don't want i.e. trimming. You need to use rstrip() function which takes argument as "the character which you want to trim from right side". e.g. rstrip('.'). If you want to do anything else let us know.

And your expected and actual output looks same so I don't understand what you want to say.

[edited]After your comment I understood what you want to say:

```
with open("strings.txt") as inf:
    for line in inf:
        line = line.rstrip(" .")  #added space and .(period) to strip
        if line.isalnum():
            print("{} was ok".format(line))
        else:
            print("{} was invalid".format(line))
```

Comment: Hi, the two outputs are not the same. check the last line:            ++-+-+--+--+-+>-<+-<<_<-+>>++ was invalid.                            ++-+-+--+--+-+>-<+-<<_<-+>>++. was invalid.                           Do you see the period before was invalid in the third line? That is the error. where did that come from is the thing I didn't understand. I think the code is adding a period at the end?

Comment: Input files has the period(.) at the end you have to strip it as well, that is what they are expecting.

Comment: Hi when I tried the code with line = line.rstrip(" .") it created another error. It added another character. in this case "3". look the difference: my output: -+>-<+-<<_<-+>>++.22323 was invalid. AND correct output: -+>-<+-<<_<-+>>++.2232 was invalid.

Comment: I ran the code in IDLE and it is not giving me such error. I don't know what exactly you are doing but it's working for me.

Comment: Hi, if you are familiar with viope.com, It is a self study environment. So when I checked the code there it gave me the above error I mentioned. But thank you so much for all the suggestions. May be I will email my teacher why it has such error.